# pass URL parameter to loaded swf

Tags: actionscript-3

I have html page pass parameter to swf:

```
<param name="movie" value="Template.swf?xmlName=63">
```

and I can access the parameter value in my swf file:

```
var val:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.xmlName;

so val = 63
```

But now I'm going to load another swf by the previous swf. How can I call the parameter from second (loaded) swf ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help but I did that Simpler
I accessed the var val from loaded swf :

```
var xmlTextName:String ;
var asdasd:Object;
asdasd = this.parent.parent.parent.parent;  
xmlTextName = String(asdasd.val)// xmlTextName =63
```

I don't know what or why but it is running now (:

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to use LocalConnection. Assuming both swfs are on the same domain :

Loaded SWF :

```
var connection:LocationConnection = new LocalConnection();
connection.connect("connectionName");

function yourMethod(value:String):void
{
    trace("I received "+value);
}
```

Calling SWF :

```
var connection:LocationConnection = new LocalConnection();
var param:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.xmlName;
conn.send("connectionName","yourMethod",param);
```

For more info on LocalConnection see [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html#send%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the variables the same way you did in your html

```
var val:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.xmlName;
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("second.swf?xmlName=" + val);
loader.load(urlRequest);
```